# How to convert categorical column values to column names

Tags: r, tibble

Suppose I have a tibble that looks like this:

```
Name | Category | Rank
----------------------
  A  |    a     |  1   
  A  |    b     |  2   
  A  |    c     |  3   
  A  |    d     |  4  
  B  |    a     |  2   
  B  |    b     |  3   
  B  |    c     |  4   
  B  |    d     |  5
```

How do I convert this to a table like this:

```
Name | a | b | c | d
---------------------
  A  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
  B  | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

The only way I can think of to convert is to do it manually, i.e take a subset of all the rows with that category and convert it to a column in a different tibble. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Category, values_from = Rank)`

Comment: thanks! That's exactly what I needed. I had no idea how to search for that